# How do I make someone commit suicide on Dishonored?

Tags: dishonored

I'm attempting to complete the whole game unspotted and no kills for achievement purposes. I don't understand how the don't-kill-anyone achievement works. I was told I can make people commit suicide, but I don't know how. How do I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check this source: http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Harm's_Way

Easiest way to do it is to use the posession skill.

Possess a person and walk towards a wall of light. Right in front of the wall end the possession, the person will continue to walk a bit further and will therefore kill themself in the wall.

More complicated way would be to bring a person in front of their own projectile when they are shooting at you. When they shoot, stop the time + possess the person, walk in front of the projectile and end the possession. As soon as the time continues they will be killed by their own projectile.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it's better to summarise the information in your answer. That way it'll still answer the question if the linked page changes or is deleted.

Comment: @Studoku thx for the advice/feedback. I'm pretty new around here. Edited the answer.